# Pyspark takes a lot of storage during execution

Tags: python, apache-spark, optimization, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to perform some basic transformations on CSV files. (**50-100 GB**).
When I test the code (scroll below) for smaller CSV files eg. 2GB it works fine.
But when I'm trying to run it for **55GB**, it is starting to eat up my storage quickly. Recently I run the code on a **1000Gb** disk and it eats up the whole space and **throws an error that there is no enough memory.**
I'm new to pyspark and maybe I'm doing something fundamentally wrong here. Can I somehow optimize the operations I'm doing here?

The shape of the CSV file is following:

```
longitude,latitude,time,u10,v10,rsn,sde,sf,snowc,smlt,sp,ssrd,ssr,tp,e,t2m,d2m,skt,sro
-10.5,52.099998474121094,2022-12-31 00:00:00,0.18959022,1.5606275,99.999985,0.0,-1.8626451e-09,0.0,0.0,98669.914,2784432.5,2499474.2,0.016814932,-0.0020219479,280.31668,278.18405,279.16608,0.00022139214
-10.5,52.099998474121094,2022-12-31 01:00:00,-0.43325806,1.3632796,99.999985,0.0,-1.8626451e-09,0.0,0.0,98655.35,0.0,-0.5,0.00087168254,-3.3625402e-06,279.7565,278.45627,278.88437,1.1917204e-05
```

The code I'm using:

```
    class ERA5DataProcessor:
def __init__(
    self,
    data: DataFrame,
    point__timezone: dict[tuple[float, float], str],
):
    self.initial_data = data
    self.point__timezone = point__timezone

def _get_udf_point_to_timezone_func(self) -> Any:
    point__timezone = self.point__timezone

    def get_timezone(longitude: float, latitude: float):
        return point__timezone[(longitude, latitude)]

    udf_function = udf(get_timezone)

    return udf_function

def _save(self, df: DataFrame) -> None:
    df.write.csv(
        "directory_path",
        header=True,
        compression="gzip",
    )

def process(self) -> DataFrame:
    """ """

    logger.info("Adding transformations to dataframe")
    df = self.initial_data

    # Ensure order
    df = df.orderBy("longitude", "latitude", "time")

    # Remove fractions from coordinates
    df = df.withColumn("latitude", round(col("latitude"), 1))
    df = df.withColumn("longitude", round(col("longitude"), 1))

    # Convert units and round
    df = df.withColumn("snow_density", round(col("rsn") / 1000, 2))
    df = df.withColumn("snow_depth", round(col("sde") * 1000, 2))
    df = df.withColumn("surface_pressure", round(col("sp") / 100, 2))
    df = df.withColumn("two_meter_temperature", round(col("t2m") - 273.15, 2))
    df = df.withColumn(
        "two_meter_dewpoint_temperature", round(col("d2m") - 273.15, 2)
    )
    df = df.withColumn("skin_temperature", round(col("skt") - 273.15, 2))
    df = df.withColumn("total_evaporation", round(col("e") * 1000, 2))
    df = df.withColumn("snowfall", round(col("sf") * 1000, 2))
    df = df.withColumn("surface_runoff", round(col("sro") * 1000, 2))
    df = df.withColumn("snowmelt", round(col("smlt") * 1000, 2))
    df = df.withColumn("total_precipitation", round(col("tp") * 1000, 2))
    df = df.withColumn("u10", round(col("u10"), 2))
    df = df.withColumn("v10", round(col("v10"), 2))
    df = df.withColumn("snow_cover", round(col("snowc"), 2))
    df = df.withColumn("surface_solar_radiation_downwards", round(col("ssrd"), 2))
    df = df.withColumn("surface_net_solar_radiation", round(col("ssr"), 2))

    df.drop(
        "u10",
        "v10",
        "rsn",
        "sde",
        "sf",
        "snowc",
        "smlt",
        "sp",
        "ssrd",
        "ssr",
        "tp",
        "e",
        "t2m",
        "d2m",
        "skt",
        "sro",
    )

    # Disperse data
    df = df.withColumn(
        "total_precipitation",
        round(
            col("total_precipitation")
            - when(hour("time") == 1, 0).otherwise(
                lag(col("total_precipitation"), 1).over(
                    Window.partitionBy("longitude", "latitude").orderBy(
                        "longitude", "latitude", "time"
                    )
                )
            ),
            2,
        ),
    )
    df = df.withColumn(
        "surface_solar_radiation_downwards",
        round(
            col("surface_solar_radiation_downwards")
            - when(hour("time") == 1, 0).otherwise(
                lag(col("surface_solar_radiation_downwards"), 1).over(
                    Window.partitionBy("longitude", "latitude").orderBy(
                        "longitude", "latitude", "time"
                    )
                )
            ),
            2,
        ),
    )
    df = df.withColumn(
        "snowmelt",
        round(
            col("snowmelt")
            - when(hour("time") == 1, 0).otherwise(
                lag(col("snowmelt"), 1).over(
                    Window.partitionBy("longitude", "latitude").orderBy(
                        "longitude", "latitude", "time"
                    )
                )
            ),
            2,
        ),
    )
    df = df.withColumn(
        "surface_runoff",
        round(
            col("surface_runoff")
            - when(hour("time") == 1, 0).otherwise(
                lag(col("surface_runoff"), 1).over(
                    Window.partitionBy("longitude", "latitude").orderBy(
                        "longitude", "latitude", "time"
                    )
                )
            ),
            2,
        ),
    )
    df = df.withColumn(
        "snowfall",
        round(
            col("snowfall")
            - when(hour("time") == 1, 0).otherwise(
                lag(col("snowfall"), 1).over(
                    Window.partitionBy("longitude", "latitude").orderBy(
                        "longitude", "latitude", "time"
                    )
                )
            ),
            2,
        ),
    )
    df = df.withColumn(
        "surface_net_solar_radiation",
        round(
            col("surface_net_solar_radiation")
            - when(hour("time") == 1, 0).otherwise(
                lag(col("surface_net_solar_radiation"), 1).over(
                    Window.partitionBy("longitude", "latitude").orderBy(
                        "longitude", "latitude", "time"
                    )
                )
            ),
            2,
        ),
    )
    df = df.withColumn(
        "total_evaporation",
        round(
            col("total_evaporation")
            - when(hour("time") == 1, 0).otherwise(
                lag(col("total_evaporation"), 1).over(
                    Window.partitionBy("longitude", "latitude").orderBy(
                        "longitude", "latitude", "time"
                    )
                )
            ),
            2,
        ),
    )
    df = df.withColumn(
        "total_evaporation",
        round(
            col("total_evaporation")
            - when(hour("time") == 1, 0).otherwise(
                lag(col("total_evaporation"), 1).over(
                    Window.partitionBy("longitude", "latitude").orderBy(
                        "longitude", "latitude", "time"
                    )
                )
            ),
            2,
        ),
    )

    # Add local time
    utc_to_local_time_func = self._get_udf_point_to_timezone_func()
    df = df.withColumn(
        "local_time",
        from_utc_timestamp(
            col("time"), utc_to_local_time_func(col("longitude"), col("latitude"))
        ),
    )

    # Execute / Save
    logger.info("Start processing the data")
    self._save(df)
```

Comment: What is the exact error you are seeing? Because memory (RAM) != storage (disks)

Comment: Basically, I was tracking all parameters and the disk storage was short even with 1000Gb. I tried to replicate now this issue locally and I got another error. But still, it eats up all disk space.
`Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 7 in stage 6.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 7.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 756) (192.168.1.114 executor driver): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

Comment: Based on that error you've shared, it suggests it's not a disk issue, but an OOM issue. If you're trying to process more data than you have available memory, this may happen. You can try using a combination of [persist](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.spark.persist.html), [cache](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.cache.html), or [checkpointing](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.checkpoint.html).

Comment: I'd start by removing `df = df.orderBy("longitude", "latitude", "time")` -- this operation collects the whole dataframe to one executor, which first maxes out its heap then starts spilling sort buffers to disk and eventually (one of two) fills up the entire disk or itself OOMs. Next, I'd consider changing compression `df.write.csv(...compression="gzip")` to something splittable.

Comment: What data format you suggest in this case? Parquet?
And these running differences I'm performing this window order by ensuring that it is sorted right?

Comment: #1 - yes parquet with compression=snappy. #2 - yes your order by in windowspec does the sorting. BTW, you dont need order by "longitude", "latitude" since you partition by those fields.